# parameterize think time LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

Is it possible to parameterize the think time for a script. Of course taken into account that all think times in the script should be of the same duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All think times should not be fixed.  They should be a variation of the natural recorded think time.  You can adjust the use of think time in the run time settings to vary the as recorded values by a percentage, such as 80-120%

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: YES it is possible.

The ThinkTime is just a float, so you can use any variable for it.

I personally prefer to have a global called `tt_general`, that I can change depending on what's happening (if needed). Of course some places in the scripts have to have different values, but you can parametrize them too if you want.

Also remember the run-time settings think-time settings, where you can set a random percentage (ex. 50% to 150%) to vary the actual think-time each time it's used.